# Problems converting AppEngine backend into module

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to convert an AppEngine application, which used a backend into one using an module (as recommended by Google).

I converted the backends.yaml with backends_conversion.py app.yaml backends.yaml

During 
        appcfg.py update producer.yaml

I than received the error, that the version "producer" already existed and that I should change the module name.

I didn't do that (because I use the module name as an taskqueue target). Instead I stopped and deleted the running backend version.

Upload the module worked afterwards.

But queuing task (via taskqueue) does not work (ie no instance of the module is started).

Also trying to  address the module from the browser (producer.appid.appspot.com) prduces an http 503.

What's wrong?

[Update]
We are adressing the backend explicitly:

```
taksqueue.add(..., target='producer')
```

The taskqueue documentation does not say how to do that with modules.

[Update]
producer.yaml

```
admin_console:
  pages:
  - name: Initialize
    url: /init
api_version: '1'
application: lpsng2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: '1'
builtins:
- remote_api: 'on'
default_expiration: 8d
env_variables:
  TMP: C:\temp
handlers:
- login: admin
  mime_type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon,
  secure: optional
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
  url: /favicon.ico
- login: admin
  mime_type: image/png
  secure: optional
  static_files: static/images/lpsng_icon_os_144.png
  upload: static/images/lpsng_icon_os_144.png
  url: /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
- login: admin
  mime_type: application/x-chrome-extension
  secure: optional
  static_files: static/lpsng.crx
  upload: static/lpsng.crx
  url: /static/lpsng.crx
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  mime_type: image/png
  secure: optional
  static_files: static/\1.png
  upload: static/(.*).png
  url: /static/(.*).png
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  mime_type: image/jpeg
  secure: optional
  static_files: static/\1.jpg
  upload: static/(.*).jpg
  url: /static/(.*).jpg
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_dir: static
  url: /static
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/lib/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/lib/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/lib/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/css/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/css/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/css/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/mode/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/mode/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/mode/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/mode/json/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/mode/json/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/mode/json/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/mode/python/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/mode/python/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/mode/python/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/theme/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/theme/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/theme/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/worker/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/worker/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/worker/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/\2
  upload: source/lib/ace/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/lib/ace/\2/\3/\4
  upload: source/lib/ace/(.*)/(.*) /(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/lib/ace/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: buildout/\2
  upload: buildout/(.*)
  url: /js/(.*)/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: buildcss/\1
  upload: buildcss/(.*)
  url: /css/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/\2/\3
  upload: dummy/dummy.txt
  url: /source/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)
- http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
  login: admin
  secure: optional
  static_files: source/\2
  upload: dummy/dummy.txt
  url: /source/(.*)/(.*)
- script: main.app
  secure: optional
  url: .*
inbound_services:
- xmpp_message
instance_class: B8
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: 2.5.2
- name: markupsafe
  version: '0.15'
- name: jinja2
  version: '2.6'
- name: PIL
  version: 1.1.7
module: producer
runtime: python27
skip_files: (?:^(.*/)?app\.yaml)|(?:^(.*/)?app\.yml)|(?:^(.*/)?index\.yaml)|(?:^(.*/)?index\.yml)|(?:^(.*/)?#.*#)|(?:^(.*/)?.*~)|(?:^(.*/)?.*\.py[co])|(?:^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*)|(?:^(.*/)?\..*)|(?:^dev/(.*))|(?:^build/(.*))|(?:(.*/source/.*))|(?:^source1/lib/([^\/]*)$)|(?:^dist/(.*)$)|(?:^data/blob/(.*))|(?:^data/log/(.*))|(?:^data/temp/(.*))|(?:^data/db/(.*))|(?:^conf/standalone[.](.*))|(?:^conf/enterprise[.](.*))|(?:^standalone/(.*))|(?:^Output/(.*))|(?:^Microsoft.VC90.CRT/(.*))|(?:^notUsed/(.*))|(?:^(.*)\.pxd)
threadsafe: true
version: '2'
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I'm facing the same issue and am eagerly hoping that someone will chime in here with useful info!

Comment: I have the same issue but in Java land. I've filed a production issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No. As we have only tested modules on our staging site (and don't need any of the extra features yet), we will propably rollback to backends. I had hoped that somebody from Google would either answer or update the docs.

Comment: Can you show your producer.yaml?

Comment: Your "target" approach should work. I just tried in a test app, and the request is routed to the specified module. Can you still reproduce this? If so, let me know your app-id and I can take a closer look.

Comment: Our conversion is now working. We  wrote a new producer.yaml by hand (not a problem with the current docs), which is much simpler than the auto converted one, because  we don't need the static files for the module. We did not need a dispatch.yaml

Answer (score 1):

One approach: You can set up your [dispatch file](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing) so that certain of your task handlers are routed to a specific module. 
Note: after you make changes to your `dispatch.yaml` file, you'll need to run

```
appcfg.py update_dispatch <proj_dir>
```

Comment: I am currently targeting certain deferred tasks to a backend of a bigger memory size. For deferred, the default URL is controlled in the deferred library and is /_ah/queue/deferred. I guess I could change it but is really a hack, I would like to see a cleaner solution, why can't a queue "target" be a module name?

Comment: I filed an issue to track this. It is still not fixed as of today... https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10326

Answer (score 0):

**To start extra modules (instances) on Production**

I've finally discovered it is necessary to issue a command line instruction from my local machine.

```
$ appcfg.py update app.yaml worker.yaml
```

If the pretty little "GoogleAppEngineLauncher" does it, I've yet to discover how.